# Equivalent of "select distinct on" in mongodb

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am wondering if `mongodb` have an Equivalent function as `select distinct on` like sql.
For example if i have this query in `Sql`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (department) * FROM employees
ORDER BY department, salary DESC;
```

How can i do the same `query` in `mongodb`?
For `mongodb` i use python with `pymongo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Use `db.collection.distinct(field, query, options)`

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=distinct#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct

https://api.mongodb.com/python/1.9/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct